# XPages/JSF: Date value binding to managed bean reads but doesn't write

Tags: java, jsf, xpages

I have created a little XPage search form with a backing bean. This works great with strings, everything is bound using Expression Language and I can access the value in my bean to compose the actual search string.

However, this doesn't seem to be working for dates. I have a date field that looks like this:

```
<xp:inputText
    themeId="Field.Date"
    id="inputStartDate" value="#{Search.calStart}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

My bean has a very basic getter/setter for this:

```
public Date getCalStart() {
    return calStart;
}

public void setCalStart(Date calStart) {
    this.calStart = calStart;
}
```

The problem is that while the field will populate from the backing bean, the bean is not affected by the field. So if in my constructor I set a date field to 7/18/2014, it looks fine on my page. But if I pick a date on the page and perform a refresh, the value does not change in the bean. The dates remain `null` or whatever I've initialized them to in the bean.

Is there something about the converter (other than handling it as a Java `Date` in my bean, which I'm doing) that breaks the value binding?

Comment: it looks ok.
How are you doing the refresh? is it from a submit button? Is it a full page refresh or a partial refresh?
Also just to double check the getter is accessing your bean, if you change your initial value to a date in the past in the constructor, does the new value show up? I think sometimes today's date shows up as default depending on domino version

Comment: also can you check the import statement in your bean, is it definitely java.util.Date? sometimes the IDE will choose java.sql.Date and things like that

Comment: Just checking...  it does work fine without the converter right?

Comment: Thanks for all these responses. @CameronGregor - I have buttons trying just a partial refresh and a full refresh. I'm fairly certain I was using java.util.Date.

Comment: @DavidLeedy - I just removed the converter from the xsp and changed everything in my bean over to String and it works perfectly.

Comment: The format of the date is `13 JUL 2014` I wonder if the parser used by the converter would be choking on that somehow?

Comment: Do you have a display Errors control on the page?  That might show something.

Comment: It didn't throw any errors, but the value never changed from what it was initialized to.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with Date and Beans before but not in Xpages.
What I did was to circumvent the getter/setter with my own and within those convert to the format I want.